# gawk: why doesn't "next;" suppress lines matching a pattern?

Tags: shell, awk, gawk

I have the following awk program:

```
/.*needle.*/
{
    if ($0 != "hay needle hay")
    {
        print "yay: ", $1;
        next;
    }

    print "ya2";
    next;
}

{
    print "no";
    next;
}
```

I run it as `gawk -f test.awk < some.log > out.log` in `GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0`.

some.log:

```
hay hay hay
hay needle hay
needle
hay hay
hay
hay
```

out.log:

```
yay:  hay         
hay needle hay    
ya2               
needle            
yay:  needle      
yay:  hay         
yay:  hay         
yay:  hay
```

I expect it only to only print "ya2-new line-yay: needle".

This raises questions:

- Why is the pattern action invoked even on non-matching lines, not the unconditional action? [`The purpose of the action is to tell awk what to do once a match for the pattern is found`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Action-Overview.html#Action-Overview).
- Why doesn't `next;` suppress the printing of the matching line, as [`print` is only the "default" action](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Very-Simple.html)? We have a non-default action here. [`The next statement forces awk to immediately stop processing the current record and go on to the next record`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html#Next-Statement)
- I could and did put `match()` call inside `if()` in the default action, but why didn't this variant work?

Comment: I tried a very similar form on different data:  `awk '/424/ {if (NR==3) {print;next;}print NR;next;} {print "no";}'`  Output was as expected (Line numbers were printed if "424" was in the line except on line 3 where the line was printed.  "no" was printed otherwise.)  Also gawk.

Comment: I assume `fields[1]` is some..construct I'm not aware of that makes sense.  `$1`, which you used above would of course be the normal way to the print the first column.

Comment: Broke the MCV when minimizing it. Let me fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be a fan of the [Allman indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style). I assume the `if ($0 != ...` block is only supposed to run where the record matches `needle` -- you need to put the opening brace on the same line as the pattern.

```
/.*needle.*/ {
    if ($0 != "hay needle hay")
    {
        print "yay: ", $1;
        next;
    }

    print "ya2";
    next;
}
```

Output:

```
no
ya2
yay:  needle
no
no
no
```

In awk, newline is a terminator, like semi-colon.

What you have now is:

```
# if the line matches "needle", print it verbatim
/.*needle.*/     

# And **also**, for every line, do this:
{
    if ($0 != "hay needle hay")
    {
        print "yay: ", $1;
        next;
    }

    print "ya2";
    next;
}
```

Comment: I was just realizing this as I realized his input worked until I made it NOT a one-liner :)

Comment: I would encourage you to browse the [awk tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info)